# How to run two django apps in same server with different dynamic DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE env variables

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, environment-variables

I'm running two django application in same server. Server setup and multi settings file are created.

But I have `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env variable as dynamic and I need to set two different values.

If I change `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` variable name to something else, i'm getting error.

**Can anyone suggest some solution for this problem**.

Comment: How are you calling/running this django apps?

Comment: I'm using gunicorn as wsgi and nginx as proxy server

Comment: You have your answer bellow!, use the --settings argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `gunicorn`, for example, you could pass the settings for each gunicorn instance using `--settings=your_project.settings.production` argument.

You could do the same if you are running the apps with `runserver`(which is a bad option for production environments).

Comment: Which one i need use --settings or --DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE for setting the value of this variables

Comment: Great answer. It is `--settings`!

Comment: Use **--settings**. Take a look https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/#the-django-admin-utility